# Langchain, error raised by bedrock service Malformed input request: #: extraneous key [functions]

Tags: python, pydantic, langchain, amazon-bedrock

I have this code that just creates tags for each document. I have done it with ChatOpenAI(), and it works perfectly, but when I change to BedrockChat(), I get the error. This is the code.

```
from langchain_community.chat_models import BedrockChat,
from langchain.chains import create_tagging_chain_pydantic

class Tags(BaseModel):
    sql: str = Field(
        description="Whether the text fragment includes sql code.",
        default="False",
    )
    python: str = Field(
        description="Whether the text fragment includes python code.",
        default="False",
    )
    
tagging_chain = create_tagging_chain_pydantic(pydantic_schema=Tags, 
                                                          llm = BedrockChat(model_id="anthropic.claude-v2") , 
                                                          prompt=self.tagging_prompt)

tagging_results = tagging_chain.batch(
    inputs=[{"input": doc.page_content} for doc in docs],
    return_exceptions=True,
    config={
    "max_concurrency": 5,
    },
    )
```

I got this error:

> Error raised by bedrock service: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the InvokeModel operation: Malformed input request: #: extraneous key [functions] is not permitted#: extraneous key [function_call] is not permitted, please reformat your input and try again.

When I print this:

```
print(tagging_chain.llm_kwargs)
```

> {'functions': [{...}], 'function_call': {'name':
> 'information_extraction'}}

```
print(tagging_chain.llm_kwargs.get("functions"))
```

> [{'name': 'information_extraction', 'description': 'Extracts the relevan...e passage.', 'parameters': {...}}]

How can fix this error?